# update checkbox value using php

Tags: php, checkbox

I need to update the status.If the status is active it will be ticked else it will be un ticked.

Used $status = $_GET['status']; .But its empty.How can i solve this

```
<tr>
            <td><?php echo $id ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $site_url; ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php if($status == "1"){ ?>

            <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="Yes" checked ="true" >
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php }if ($status == "0"){ ?>

            <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="No"  >
            </td>
            <?php } ?>
            <td>    <a href="this_page.php?update=<?php echo $site_url; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Update</a></td>   
            </tr>
```

Comment: if `$_GET['status']` is empty then the checkbox will always be unticked. isn't what you are getting? there will be a value on $_GET['status'] only if `status` parameter has been passed to URL

Comment: @user8429002 you need to do it using javascript because PHP is not DOM specific language.

Comment: How can i get the updated value of status?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve **exactly**? It is very unclear with only the code and 2 lines of explanation.

Comment: @KoenHollander the php code will display the current details from db.User have the facility to update the the status value and i need it to be updated in the database too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right path, you just made a small mistake, you need to put `checked` or `checked="checked"` instead of `checked=true`

```
<td>
<?php if($status == "1"){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="Yes" checked >
</td>
<td>
<?php } if ($status == "0") { ?>
   <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="No"  >
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

You could make it more readable by writing it like this

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="Yes" <?= $status ? 'checked' : '' ?> >
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="status" value="No" <?= !$status ? 'checked' : '' ?> >
</td>
```

Comment: If you need the value then just change `value="Yes/No"` to `value="<?= $_GET['status'] ?>"`

Answer (score 2):

you must change this line :

```
<td>    <a href="this_page.php?update=<?php echo $site_url; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Update</a></td>
```

to :

```
<td>    <a href="this_page.php?status=<?php echo $site_url; ?>" class="edit_btn" >Update</a></td>
```

and then you can see the result .

Comment: Can you please explain this.

Comment: the value of the updated status wiil be sent to this_page.php and you can get this and update your database !